# Please explain this codes:

Tags: django-forms

This is my forms.py in Django app.But I have not understand the save() function specially the commit keyword. I took this code from a blog . here the writter is making a form for user registration.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from . models import Document

class NewUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")

    def save(self, commit = True):
        user = super(NewUserForm, self).save(commit = False)    
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

please explain the whole save function.